# How to filter a request for a host with mitmproxy addon if its hostname match a regex?

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I wanna implement an addon which filters and remove all request for a set of domains. All domains must match with the following regex:

```
a-.+\.xxxx\.com
```

I do not know how to get a request hostname:

```
if re.match("a-.+\.xxxx\.com", flow.request.hostname):
     # Do something
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mitmproxy, the following class is used to encapsulate request information:

```
mitmproxy.net.http.Request
```

And the contractor of the [Request](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/mitmproxy/net/http/request.py) class is:

```
def __init__(
        self,
        host: str,
        port: int,
        method: bytes,
        scheme: bytes,
        authority: bytes,
        path: bytes,
        http_version: bytes,
        headers: Union[Headers, Tuple[Tuple[bytes, bytes], ...]],
        content: Optional[bytes],
        trailers: Union[None, Headers, Tuple[Tuple[bytes, bytes], ...]],
        timestamp_start: float,
        timestamp_end: Optional[float],
):
```

So, somewhere in the platform the host and port is passed to the class instance.

The implementation uses a data class to store data:

```
@dataclass
class RequestData(message.MessageData):
    host: str
    port: int
    method: bytes
    scheme: bytes
    authority: bytes
    path: bytes
```

Therefor, to access the request hostname:

```
if re.match("a-.+\.xxxx\.com", flow.request.data.host):
     # Do something
```

---

Following method added directly into the Request class:

A getter

```
@property
def host(self) -> str:
```

A setter

```
@host.setter
def host(self, val: Union[str, bytes]) -> None:
```

So the following code is acceptable too:

```
if re.match("a-.+\.xxxx\.com", flow.request.host):
     # Do something
```